# Why I always need to run "maven clean install" before executing main java code in intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have written some code in **intellij** in **java**. Now, whenever I make any changes in my java code and run it using green run button, these changes are not reflected until I run **maven clean install**.
So right now, I have to run maven clean install before executing my java code. why this is happening, same code is executing just by green run button in my friends IDE.

Answer (score 2):

When the Rebuild Project action is delegated to Gradle or Maven, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't include the clean task/goal when rebuilding a project. If you need, you can execute the clean command before the rebuild using the Execute Before Rebuild option in the Gradle or Maven tool window.
More info here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html#trigger_goal

Answer (score 0):

the actual problem was something else.
In the target folder, .class files was not getting generated when running the program.